# How can I effect a line break in a listing's caption defined with \lstname?

Tags: listings, captions, line-breaking

I'm using the package `listings` and defined the caption as `\lstname`, so it shows the relative path and the filename when I use the input command of the listings package.

However, sometimes, the filename is too long. Is there a way to break the line or just show the filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `url` package to allow breaking in file paths, or you can use LaTeX's filename parser to extract just the basename:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,url}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\basename#1{\filename@parse{#1}\filename@base.\filename@ext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\lstinputlisting[caption=\expandafter\protect\expandafter\url\expandafter{\lstname}]{%
/c/tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp//../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/zzz.txt}

\lstinputlisting[caption=\basename{\lstname}]{%
/c/tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp//../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/zzz.txt}

\end{document}
```